# ERROR: syntax error at or near "." in copy command using java?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I am using following code:

```
query1=" SELECT distinct copy meta.amz_payment1(\"Date\", settlement_id, type, order_id, "
      + "sku, description, quantity, marketplace, fulfillment, order_city, order_state, "
      + "order_postal, product_sales, shipping_credits, promotional_rebates, "
      + "sales_tax_collected, selling_fees, fba_fees, other_transaction_fees,other, "
      + "total_fmt)"
      + "INTO meta.amz_payment1_copy\n" 
      + "from meta.amz_payment1";
stmt.executeUpdate(query1);  // line 153
```

But it shows the following error:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
>   Position: 27
>   at 
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:331)
>   at import_payment.amz_payment.importData(amz_payment.java:153)
>   at import_payment.amz_payment.<init>(amz_payment.java:69)
> ```

Comment: Do you get on which line number you get the error?

Comment: `SELECT distinct copy` is invalid SQL (unless you have a column named `copy`) . And if you want to create a new table it's better to use `create table new_table as select...` instead of the deprecated syntax `select .. into new_table`

Comment: I think the error is in the SQL statement, not in Java. Can you try executing the SQL in the console, and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query

```
INSERT INTO meta.amz_payment1_copy SELECT NEXTVAL('sequenceid'),Date,settlement_id, type, order_id,sku, description,  quantity, marketplace, fulfillment, order_city, order_state,order_postal, product_sales, shipping_credits, promotional_rebates,sales_tax_collected, selling_fees, fba_fees, other_transaction_fees,other,total_fmt
FROM meta.amz_payment1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres [syntax for `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html) is eg.

```
COPY ( select * from yaddayadda where <something> ) TO `filename`
```

And copies data from a table/view/query to a file. If you want to copy to another table, you should use

```
create table yadda_copy ... as select * from yadda
```

Cheers,